# помогите запустить крон

Tags: cron

у меня есть сайт, который расположен на выделенном виртуальном сервере и в кроне которого прописана команда

```
cd /home/admin/web/site.net.ua/public_html/;/usr/bin/php yii photo-products
```

я перенёс сайт на виртуальный хостин, где несколько другая система папок и команда изменилась на

```
cd /home/esot/site.net.ua/www/&/usr/local/php71/bin/php yii photo-products
```

но в таком виде скрипт не запускается.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с синтаксисом команды:

cd - ???

/home/esot/site.net.ua/www/ - путь к корню сайта

& - соединитель

/usr/local/php71/bin/php - путь к интерпритатору (пхп)

yii - ???

photo-products - ???

вот мой файл yii.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Yii console bootstrap file.
 */

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/console/config/bootstrap.php';

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main-local.php'
);

$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$exitCode = $application->run();
exit($exitCode);
```

Какая функция здесь будет принимать аргумент "photo-products"?

Comment: `&` — не тот разделитель команд, который вам нужен. используйте `&&`

Comment: Напишите хостеру, они всегда сами настраивают, по желанию пользователя, опишите просьбу и что хотите в итоге получить, они все за вас сделают, а вы потом зайдете и посмотрите, как они это сделали.

Answer (score 2):

**cd** - переход в директорию

**& скорее всего &&**: cd /home/esot/site.net.ua/www/ && /usr/local/php71/bin/php yii photo-products - перейти в директории и запустить скрипт

**yii** - фреймворк, скорее всего файл в директории /home/esot/site.net.ua/www/

**photo-products** - агрумент функции

Пример на основе другого фреймворка:
/usr/local/php71/bin/php artisan migrate, где artisan - файл в директории откуда запускается скрипт.

Можем переписать так: /usr/local/php71/bin/php /home/esot/site.net.ua/www/yii photo-products

Comment: Насколько я понимаю крон будет пытаться запустить файл yii.php  в папке /home/esot/site.net.ua/www/ передавая в этот файл аргумент какой-то функции "photo-products". Так?

Comment: Почти так. Агрумент передан в скрипт yii, а уже в самом скрипте будет решено, что делать с переменной.
Вот пример: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Почти так, это значит не функция принимает аргумент, а скрипт. 
В файле подключаются библиотеки: 
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/console/config/bootstrap.php';
Здесь происходит подключение и выполнение кода с той же областью видимости (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php). Соотствественно в этих скриптах может происходить получение и обработка переменной. 
Где происходит обработка не отвечу, yii не изучал.